# Is it possible to rearrange my list so that my list indexes matches the hour of the day?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of 24 prices between each hour of the day and night.

example:

```
Pricelist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
```

I have also imported time that returns the current time: eg. N = 13.
I want to rearrange the Pricelist so that PriceList[N] gets put at index 0 in the list, and the next price gets index N+1.

The goal is to get a following list if N = 13:

```
Pricelist = [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: Use dictionary instead of list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [list slicing and concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#common-sequence-operations) to achieve it:

```py
Pricelist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
N = 13

Pricelist_new = Pricelist[N-1:] + Pricelist[:N-1]
# [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: Slicing the list seems like the way to go, but now I encountered a new problem: The code to generate variable N is as follows: 

*import time
named_tuple = time.localtime() # get struct_time
time_string = time.strftime("%H", named_tuple) 

N = time_string

Now when I run the code after this is done I get error message: 
10 N = time_string
11 
---> 12 Pricelist_new = Pricelist[N-1:] + Pricelist[:N-1]
     13 # [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'.

Is this fixable?

Comment: Because you get the hour string. Use `N = int(time_string)` to convert the string to integer. BWT, you can directly assign `N` by `named_tuple.tm_hour`.

Answer (score 0):

So you need that N needs to be equal to the hour of the day?
Have you tried

```
from datetime import datetime
currentDateAndTime = datetime.now()

N=currentDateAndTime.hour
```

This will make that N equals to the local hour